# Bind 2 different applications GET endpoints

Tags: java, api, get, endpoint, restlet

I want a GET endpoint api/v1/getNames to also bind to another application's GET endpoint user/getData. Please note the different Restlet Context here. Is there an efficient way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
  Router router = new Router(getContext())
  router.attach("api/v1/getNames", UsersServerResource.class); 
  router.attach("user/getData", UsersServerResource.class); 
}
```

If you want the server resource to be handled by both `api/v1/getNames` and `user/getData` endpoints. (That is, if I understand your question correctly)

And as a note, REST api endpoints usually should be noun-based, not verbs.

So your endpoint should be better be like:

```
router.attach("api/v1/names", UsersServerResource.class); 
router.attach("api/v1/users", UsersServerResource.class);
```